# Render and Open SSRS Report to PDF in another window (instead of downloading)

Tags: c#, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I am having an issue rendering an SSRS report to PDF in MS Edge. It presents a new window as desired but instead of opening the SSRS report in PDF, it downloads the file directly and not showing the report.

Here's the code:

```
string pdfReportURL = reportServer + "/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?%2fOps%2fCPM%2fCompleted+Flow+Sheet+Activities&PatientID=" + PatientId + "&CalendarDate=" + dateOfServiceString + "&rs:Command=Render&rs:Format=PDF&rs:ClearSession=True";


ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "newWindow", String.Format("window.open('{0}','_blank',resizable=1,scrollbars=1);", pdfReportURL), true);
```

If this is impossible to fix, how can I open and render SSRS to PDF in another window using IFrame

Comment: Why not open the downloaded file and specify the full pathname of the file?

Comment: Client does not want it downloaded. They want it initially open in a new MS Edge window

Comment: All you need to do is to put the URL into a MS Edge Address (URL) and navigate to page.  If you are putting into a IFRAME  then add a browser to the IFRAME and put the URL into the browser. See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.clientscriptmanager.registerstartupscript?view=netframework-4.8